# Writing A User-Named File to a specific directory

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm trying to write a file to a specific directory.  And the name of the file is an input from the user.  I have figured out how to get the name and insert it into as the filename, but I don't know how to save it to a specific directory.

```
std::cout << "Enter topic name: ";
std::string topicName;
std::getline(std::cin, topicName);

std::ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(topicName.c_str(), std::ios_base::app);
```

This code works,but it saves the file to the current directory.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To save it to a specific directory you need to use the full path (or relative path based on the current working directory) to that directory. You can append the file name to the path of the directory if you want or use an OS function to change the working directory to the path you want.

Comment: I'm actually quite new at C++ and still learning.  Can you teach how to append path to the filename?

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks!  You mentioning appending the path made me realize it.

I added:
std::string pathTo = "/home/xxx/myfolder/"+topicName;

outfile.open(pathTo.c_str(), std::ios_base::app);

That added it to the specific directory with the specific name assigned by the user.  Thanks!

Comment: Please remove the ".c_str()". std:ofstream accepts a std::string as file name paramerer. If you are using C++17 you could use std::filesystem::path for the file name, which also solves your directory problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out after what Konrad mentioned.

```
std::string pathTo = "/home/xxx/myfolder/"+topicName;
outfile.open(pathTo.c_str(), std::ios_base:app);
```

I had to created another string and concatenate the full path name and used that string instead in the ostream.
That worked fine.

Comment: That was me.. :)